# How to pass file name from Filebeat to Logstash?

Tags: logstash, graylog2, filebeat

How to pass each log file name from Filebeat to Logstash?

I want to see in Graylog source file names to do deep analysis.

I studied the documentation but have not found an explanation. Can you help me?

Answer (score 5):

Filebeat includes the filename in the [`source`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/exported-fields-log.html#_source) field which is contained in every event it ships.

Answer (score 1):

Given answer is right but If you separately want to send filename or anything else from Filebeat to Logstash you can pass it using

```
fields:  
    key: value
```

in filebeat.prospectors as in below screenshot:

[image]
And You can access it in logstash configuration using

```
[fields][buildversion]
            or
"%{[fields][buildversion]}"
```